# Is there any way in Java to access information about a type at runtime without fully loading the class?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a reference to a java.lang.Class which is on my classpath and look at the members on it with reflection.  The trouble is, I'm trying to do this with only an incomplete classpath.  By this I mean that the classpath contains all the classes I am interested in, but does not necessarily contain further classes which these classes might depend on.  Therefore it is not possible to fully load the class in the normal way.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) to parse the `.class` file without loading the class

Answer (score 2):

It should be fine, you should only encounter ClassNotFound errors when those classes are invoked and need to be loaded. I don't think this will be the case if you are not instantiating instances of the classes, even if those classes import the others that are missing.
However, if your class makes any static initializer references to the unavailable classes then exceptions may be thrown even without class instantiations.

Answer (score 1):

The classes won't be loaded until they are referenced, which means that if you don't instantiate your class only the classes referenced in the classes [static initialization block](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) (or referenced in another static initialization expression) should need to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If these classes which might be needed are not in the classpath (for example if it needs another jar which is not referenced), you are likely to encounter an error.

It won't happen when you will load the class, however, but will happen if you call a method on it which requires these unreferenced classes. So, depending on what you want to do (basing on title, accessing basic information from the type), it might work, as long as what you need doesn't involve a call to these other classes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to "extend" your classpath. You can create a custom class loader (you'll have to read the doc, I did it 5 years ago, but I don't remember the details).

So you can create that class loader (only override some very simple methods that maps the name of the class to some URL to read the bytes from), instance it, and ask it for classes.

You  can access that loaded classes vía reflection. But never statically.

If you give the classloader a parent it will "inherit" the classes already in classpath. If not it will use the bootstrap classloader.

*Edit* if there are not depended classes, this will raise an error. You should create a class loader that has ALL the directly referenced classes.